# Using a modifier as a function in Solidity

Tags: solidity

I have a modifier in my code:

```
modifier isOkay(address addr) {
    if (balances[addr].balance == 0)
        throw;
    _;
}
```

Which I used thus:

```
function whatever() isOkay(msg.sender) {
    // whatever
}
```

I want to use the modifier as a boolean test insider of other functions, thus:

```
function other_function() {
    // some other function
    if (isOkay(msg.sender)) {
       // do whatever
    }
}
```

Is that possible? I see an obvious way to do it (have the modifier call the function), but I wonder if there's a more elegant pattern to use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, but you can make some consistent and readable code

```
pragma solidity 0.4.19; 

contract Okay {

    modifier onlyIfOkay() {
        require(isOkay(msg.sender));
        _;
    }

    function isOkay(address checkOkay) public pure returns(bool isIndeed) {
        // check something
        return checkOkay==checkOkay;
    }

    function restricted() public view onlyIfOkay {
        // carry on
    }

}
```

That gives you the option of using `isOkay(addr)`/`!isOkay(addr)` when needed inside functions and a simple modifier for guarding functions (it assumes the most common case, we need to check the sender).

There are lots of ways to work out case-by-case details. I would urge caution/avoidance of a somewhat hazardous pattern:

`modifier isOkay() {
  _;
  if(!ok) revert();
}`

The hazard is in putting `_;` in front of the modifier steps because that might help camouflage a bug.

For the benefit of others:

If a modified function `returns` (looks normal enough to a reviewer), the `modifier` code will not execute because it won't get a chance to. It would be equivalent to:

```
return;
if(!ok) revert(); // <= unreachable code doesn't run
```

It will only seem like the `modifier` is in play in every case. Consequently, I'm leery about using that style.

Comment: I didn't know about that. You're right. Looks a bit hazardous. Can a modifier return a value?  Also, will the calling code get inserted twice (once for each '_')?

Comment: My understanding is it will put the top code block, then the modifier, then the bottom code block, so looks nice and does what you want, but I don't use it owing to the hazard.

Comment: Modifiers aren't intended to be used for this kind of thing. They should be used to validate conditions prior to execution of a function. If you wish to do something like this it is much cleaner and a better practice to have this kind of conditional logic inside a function

Comment: Are u sure about this hazardous pattern? It seems it is not true or maybe was fixed in some version.

Comment: Whats the point of the modifiers? I mean, I would be able to create a function that validates stuff and then call the "validation function" on my other function, right?

Answer (score 4):

I think the safer way to do this is to decompose the modifier into a function that does the check and then invoke that function in the modifier.

For example:

```
function hasNonZeroBalance(address addr) returns (bool) {
    return balances[addr].balance != 0;
}

modifier isOkay(address addr) {
    if (!hasNonZeroBalance(addr))
        throw;
    _;
}

function whatever() isOkay(msg.sender) {
    // whatever
}

function other_function() {
    // some other function
    if (hasNonZeroBalance(msg.sender)) {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```

where the function is called `hasNonZeroBalance()` (rather than `hasZeroBalance()`) to keep the semantics aligned with those of the `isOkay()` modifier.  Thus instead of calling `isOkay()` you just call `hasNonZeroBalance()`.

A bit redundant - but if only a few of the conditionals in your modifier need this it won't add much heft to the code and keeps the logic clear and thus the contract safer.