# What does the single line "_;" in OpenZeppelin's onlyMinter() function do?

Tags: erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts, mint

In onlyMinter(), there is a line with only `_;`. I'm having troubles adding a minter address, so I'm just checking the various contracts that go into ERC721. The function is

```
modifier onlyMinter() {
    require(isMinter(msg.sender));
    _;
}
```

What does `_;` do? Is it an error?

Answer (score 2):

Modifier code is merged with the modified function. `_` is the wildcard that tells the compiler where to put the function code relative to the modifier code.

Have a look over here for explanation, examples: [Using a modifier as a function in Solidity](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/27111/using-a-modifier-as-a-function-in-solidity)

Hope it helps.